# Creat Custom keyboard for android which replace the Default android keyboard through service

Tags: android

I am creating the layout of my keyboard and i want to replace this keyboard with the default android android keyboard.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

In all seriousness, take a look at the SoftKeyboard demo in the SDK. That's where you should start. You won't be able to force a user to use your new keyboard, though. They must choose to replace their current input method with yours. That demo shows you how that fits into the settings too.